# What is the elegant way to select n latest (by date) entries in data.frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following data frame (just an example)

```
Date StudentID Gender Grade
```

The data frame is unbalanced in a sense that there are significantly more males than females. I need to select from the data frame all females and the same number of males with the latest date entries. The dates are given as Date type. The data frame is unsorted and there are multiple rows that may have the same date. 
What is the most elegant way to perform this task?

Comment: You first should provide a reproducible example rather expecting other people doing all the work for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supposing `dat` is your dataframe and it is ordered by `Date`, you could use:

```
rbind(tail(dat[dat&Gender=="Male",], 10),
      tail(dat[dat&Gender=="Female",], 10))
```

or:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)[, tail(.SD, 10) , by = Gender]
```

or:

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>% group_by(Gender) %>% do(tail(., 10))
```

Each will select the last 10 cases for both groups.

Comment: What if the data frame is not ordered by Date and I prefer to keep it this way (it is ordered by other columns)?

Comment: Then just make sure you don't alter the original data frame.

Comment: @Sasha If you want to select the lastest `Date` entries, you have to order somehow by `Date`; whether that is in a new dataframe or the original one. You can always change it back to the original ordering afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can create a data frame for the males:

```
# subset all male records
df1     <- df[df$Gender == 'Male', ]

# sort by date in descending order (most recent first)
df2     <- df1[rev(order(df1$Date)),]

# retain same number of rows as number of females
df.male <- df2[1:sum(df$Gender == 'Female'), ]
```

To create a data frame for the females, you just need this:

```
df.female <- df[df$Gender == 'Female', ]
```

You can combine them using this:

```
df.all <- rbind(df.male, df.female)
```

Note that I assume that your `Date` column is already actually of class Date and not something else, like a factor or character.  In the event that it is *not* a date, then you will have to convert it first in order to sort by the date.